# How to relate zero K to statistical analogue of entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics

Here we have a common equation of entropy

$$ S = klnW $$

At 0 K we have only one microstate and W is 1, therefore S = 0

Now we can consider another representation of this equation

$$ S = klnQ + \frac{U}{T}\ $$

How can we use this equation to explain that at 0 K the entropy will also be equal to 0?

Comment: That would require that $Q\rightarrow1$ and $U\rightarrow0$ faster than $T\rightarrow0$ as $T\rightarrow0$.

Answer (score 1):

The internal energy is defined as $\displaystyle U=Nk_BT^2\left(\frac{\partial \ln(Z)}{\partial T}\right)_V$

and the partition function $Z$ is the sum over the states

$$\displaystyle Z=\sum_i e^{-\epsilon_i/(k_BT)}\quad \text{and we shall need} \quad \frac{\partial \ln(Z)}{\partial T}=\frac{1}{Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial T}$$

The entropy is therefore $\displaystyle S=Nk_B\ln(Z)+Nk_BT\left(\frac{\partial \ln(Z)}{\partial T}\right)_V$

The derivative works out as $\displaystyle \frac{\partial \ln(Z)}{\partial T}=\frac{1}{Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial T}=\frac{\sum_i \epsilon_ie^{-\epsilon_i/(k_BT)}}{k_BT^2\sum_i e^{-\epsilon_i/(k_BT)}}$

and $\displaystyle T\frac{\partial \ln(Z)}{\partial T}=\frac{\sum_i \epsilon_ie^{-\epsilon_i/(k_BT)}}{k_BT\sum_i e^{-\epsilon_i/(k_BT)}}\tag{1}$

As $T$ tends to $0$ the exponentials tend to zero which means that $Z=\sum_i e^{-\epsilon_i/(k_BT)}\to 0$ and thus in the entropy $\ln(Z)\to -\infty$. However in the derivative eqn. 1, we are left with $0/0$ which is undefined. There may be an elegant mathematical way of evaluating eqn 1 in the limit, however, if we look at term by term we get for the first

$$\displaystyle \frac{\epsilon_0e^{-\epsilon_0/(k_BT)}   }{k_BT\sum_i e^{-\epsilon_i/(k_BT)}}=\frac{\epsilon_0}{k_BT(1+e^{-(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_0))/(k_BT)}+\cdots )}\overset{T\to 0}\to\frac{1}{0}=\infty$$

and as the exponentials tend to zero this is true of each of the terms with energy $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\cdots$ in the numerator. The entropy at $t\to 0$ is therefore given by $S=-\infty+\infty =0$ on the assumption that we can subtract similar infinities.